# VLC player broken installation

Tags: vlc, software-installation

I tried to install Vlc player with Software Center. Unfortunately my lost my network connection. So the downloading failed. After getting the network connection I tried again to install. Now the problem arises.

> The progress tab shows downloading 0 bytes of 158 bytes

And no downloading is happening. After sometimes an error window pops up and tells and check your internet connetcion. I tried after shutdown, update packages, so many times. 
Need Vlc and need Help.

Comment: If you run a `sudo apt-get purge vlc`, does it try to remove any packages?

Comment: `vipin@vipin-Satellite-C640:~/tor$ sudo apt-get purge vlc  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
Package vlc is not installed, so not removed  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like vlc was ever installed. To fix the issue, you might want to try (in a terminal):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

For more information about the `apt-get` package manager, you can also run:

```
man apt-get
```